# Let $A:=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^2=x^4-2 x^3, x \in[-1,0)\right\}$. Calculate $\sigma_1(A)$

Tags: integration

Let $A:=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^2=x^4-2 x^3, x \in[-1,0)\right\}$. Calculate $\sigma_1(A)$.

I have defined $y=\sqrt{x^4-2x^3}$.
Then I calculated the Jacobian matrix which is
$\frac{1}{2}*(x^4-2x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*(4x^3-6x^2)$ ist.
Then times the transpose is the expression squared.
Then take the square root of the absolute value and the expression $\frac{1}{2}*(x^4-2x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*(4x^3-6x^2)$ remains
Then I calculated the integral from -1 to 0 above and came up with $-\sqrt{3}$ which somehow can't be right.
$\sigma_k(\Phi(A))=\int_A \sqrt{\left|\operatorname{det} D \Phi^{\top} D \Phi\right|} \mathrm{d} \lambda_k$ .
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is $\sigma_1(A)$? I see you have a definition at the bottom, but what are $\Phi$ and $\lambda_k$ in this context?